# Filtering whit a dropdown an Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, filter, dropdown

I'm trying to filter with a dropdown, but I'm doing something wrong.
It seems that the first "if statement" is true but even so it's adding the style to disable the tbody. Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

```js
tbody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
dropdown = document.getElementById('filter_years');
function filterByYear(){
   dropdown_value = dropdown.value
    for (let i = 0; i < tbody.length; i++) {
      years = tbody[i].getAttribute("data-year");
      if(dropdown_value == years[i]){
         tbody[i].classList.remove("cat_hide_year");
         } else if(dropdown_value == "2020-2022") {
            tbody[i].classList.remove("cat_hide_year");
         }
         else{
            tbody[i].classList.add("cat_hide_year");
         }
      }
}
dropdown.onchange = filterByYear;
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
#filter_dropdown{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.cat_hide_year{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_dropdown">
  <select id="filter_years">
    <option value="2020-2022">2020-2022</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody data-year="2022" class="">
    <tr><td>2022</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2021" class="">
    <tr><td>2021</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2020" class="">
    <tr><td>2020</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `[i]` in `if(dropdown_value == years[i]){` which does not belong there, but actually I think you are over-complicating  this.

Note I changed the first option value to "all"

```js
const tbody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
document.getElementById('filter_years').addEventListener("change", function() {
  const dropdown_value = this.value;
  tbody.forEach(tb => tb.hidden = dropdown_value !== "all" && dropdown_value !== tb.dataset.year)
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#filter_dropdown {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_dropdown">
  <select id="filter_years">
    <option value="all">2020-2022</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody data-year="2022" class="">
    <tr>
      <td>2022</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2021" class="">
    <tr>
      <td>2021</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2020" class="">
    <tr>
      <td>2020</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the [i] in the if statement

```js
// AS-IS
if(dropdown_value == years[i]){

// TO-BE
if(dropdown_value == years){
```

```js
tbody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
dropdown = document.getElementById('filter_years');
function filterByYear(){
   dropdown_value = dropdown.value
    for (let i = 0; i < tbody.length; i++) {
      years = tbody[i].getAttribute("data-year");
      if(dropdown_value == years){
         tbody[i].classList.remove("cat_hide_year");
         } else if(dropdown_value == "2020-2022") {
            tbody[i].classList.remove("cat_hide_year");
         }
         else{
            tbody[i].classList.add("cat_hide_year");
         }
      }
}
dropdown.onchange = filterByYear;
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
#filter_dropdown{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.cat_hide_year{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_dropdown">
  <select id="filter_years">
    <option value="2020-2022">2020-2022</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody data-year="2022" class="">
    <tr><td>2022</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2021" class="">
    <tr><td>2021</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-year="2020" class="">
    <tr><td>2020</td></tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```